# Problema enviar valor do input (que é atualizado num While) para outra página via POST

Tags: php, html, sql, while

Tenho um laço de repetição `while` que cria campos de acordo com o número de municípios do cliente. Preciso passar a variável `codmunicipio` via método *POST* para ser inserir no Banco de Dados em outra página.

No caso se tiver somente um município o *POST* funciona mas quando tem mais de um município ele continua passando somente uma variável.

Segue os trechos do código:

```
<?php    

   while($dado_ipl3 = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_ipl3)) { 

     $nome_municipio = $dado_ipl3['CIDADE'];
     $codmunicipio = $dado_ipl3['COD_CIDADE'];
?>

     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">       
         <label class="col-md-3">IPL3 Distribuição do quantitativo total de acessos fisícos em serviço por tipo de usuário (mensal)</label>                       
       </div>


  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
          <label class="col-md-3">Nome Município</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
              <input type="text" name="nome_municipio" id="nome_municipio" class="form-control" value="<?php echo"$nome_municipio" ?>"   maxlength="18" size="18" title="Nome Município">
            </div>                       
      </div> 
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
      <label class="col-md-3">Codigo Municipio</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" name="codmunicipio[]" id="codmunicipio" class="form-control numero_livre" value="<?php echo $codmunicipio; ?>"  maxlength="7" size="7">
       </div>                       
     </div> 
  </div>


 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
        <label class="col-md-3">Acesso físico P.F.</label>
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IPL3_valor_F" id="IPL3_valor_F" class="form-control numero" value="0"   maxlength="18" size="18" title="Quantitativo de Acesso físico em serviço pelo tipo da Pessoa Física">
          </div>                       
      </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
        <label class="col-md-3">Acesso físico P.J.</label>
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="IPL3_valor_J" id="IPL3_valor_J" class="form-control numero" value="0"  maxlength="18" size="18" title="Quantitativo de Acesso físico em serviço pelo tipo da Pessoa Jurídica">
          </div>                       
      </div> 
  </div>


  </div>
</div>

<?php   


   }


?>
```

pagina que recebe:

```
    $codmunicipio = $_POST['codmunicipio'];
    $valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F']; 
    $valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'];  


   $sql3 = "INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 (ano, mes, 
    fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J)

    VALUES ('$ano_upload', '$mes_uplooad', '$fistel','$codmunicipio', 
     '$valor_ipl3_f', '$valor_ipl3_j')"; 


      $resultado3 = $banco->pesquisarBD($sql3);
```

No caso quero passar todos esses campos atualizados:

```
$codmunicipio', '$valor_ipl3_f', '$valor_ipl3_j
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar:

```
<input type="text" name="nome_municipio[]" />
```

E na página onde você receberá o **$_POST** faça outro loop de repetição para pegar os valores

```
foreach ($_POST['nome_municipio'] as $pos => $valor) {
    $nome_municipo = $valor;
}
```

Comment: Continua pegando apenas um valor.

Comment: Você tem que renomear todos os inputs como array `nome_municipio[]`, quando chegar na outra página, use um `print_r($_POST)` para você ver os valores.

Comment: eu to tentando passar assim:

foreach ([$_POST['codmunicipio'], $_POST['IPL3_valor_F'], $_POST['IPL3_valor_J']] as list ($value1, $value2, $value3)) {

        $codmunicipio = $value1;, $valor_ipl3_f = $value2;, $valor_ipl3_j = $value3;

Comment: Pois eu tenho que passar o ipl3_valor_f e ipl3_valor_j para CADA municipio

Answer (score 0):

1. Quando há mais de um município, evidentemente haverá mais de um código de município, portanto, já que seu formulário contem colchetes `[ ]` no `name` do input `Codigo Municipio`, que significa que ele é enviado na forma de vetor ou array para o receptor, é necessário fazer uso de [**`foreach ()`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) para percorrer esse array.
2. Se o seu formulário está correto, os valores dos inputs `IPL3_valor_F` e `IPL3_valor_J`  estão setados sempre com valor `0`, dessa forma não há necessidade de resgatar esses valores na página insert. Basta colocar no `VALUES` da declaração `insert` o valor `0`
3. Outro detalhe é que não há qualquer indicio que `Nome Município` faz parte da declaração `insert` portanto desnecessário também recuperar esse valor.

No mais, se eu **não** estiver enganado sobre o acima exposto nos itens 2 e 3, a pagina que recebe deve ficar assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['codmunicipio'])){

    $codmunicipio = $_POST['codmunicipio'];
    //desnecessários
    //$valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F']; 
    //$valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'];
    //A cada iteração, a variável "$value" automaticamente recebe o valor de cada item do array,
    foreach ($codmunicipio as $value) {
         $sql3 = "INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 (ano, mes, 
            fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J)
            VALUES ('$ano_upload', '$mes_uplooad', '$fistel','$value', 
             0, 0)"; 
    }

}
```

**No caso de passar todos esses campos** `$codmunicipio', '$valor_ipl3_f', '$valor_ipl3_j` **atualizados:**

```
if (isset($_POST['codmunicipio'])){

    $codmunicipio = $_POST['codmunicipio'];
    $valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F']; 
    $valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'];

    for($i = 0; $i<count($codmunicipio); $i++) {

       $sql3 = "INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 (ano, mes, 
            fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J)
            VALUES ('$ano_upload', '$mes_uplooad', '$fistel','$codmunicipio[$i]', 
             '$valor_ipl3_f[$i]', '$valor_ipl3_j[$i]')"; 
    }

}
```

> sendo que nos inputs `IPL3_valor_F` e `IPL3_valor_J` devem conter colchetes no final dos respectivos `name`